# Code to hide multiple rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check the cell value and based on that, 5 rows should be hidden.

For example if the **S4** cell value is **<=0** then it should hide Rows from **4 to 8** and then again it should check **S9** cell value will and if it is **<=0** then it should hide rows from **9 to 13** and so on.

Like this I have more than 1000 rows.  Is there a better way handle this?  Please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called a "For loop" that helps you go through a big number of rows without having to write down every single one of them.
Read about them here: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

I will give you a basic example:

```
Sub hideSomeRows()

Dim currentRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = 1000 'or any other last row you want to check

For currentRow = 1 To lastRow Step 5
    If Range("S" & currentRow).Value <= 0 Then
        Rows(currentRow & ":" & currentRow + 4).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next currentRow


End Sub
```

This will loop through every 5th row between row 1 and row 1000 and hide itself and the next 4 rows if there is a negative value or zero in column S of the inspected row.

I kept the code as simple as possible, but you should really consider qualifying "Range" before using it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) is a very good discussion of why it is important and how to do it. 
Find some quick code snippets [here](http://codevba.com/excel/set_worksheet.htm#.Xr0qi8CxVhE) showing how to define the workbook and the worksheet you are working on as variables in your code. 
And [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/) is in-depth information about working with worksheets:

The gist of it: Do

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("!!YOURWORKSHEETNAME!!") 'replace !!YOURWORKSHEETNAME!! with the name of your worksheet
```

and then write `ws.Range` instead of just `Range`. Same goes for Rows.
Why you ask? Try looking at another worksheet before executing your macro and you will see, that your macro is going to always interpret `Range` as a range of the last active worksheet if not told otherwise!

Comment: + For a well explained answer. Maybe replace `1000` by the last used row and it's solid =). FYI, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9758194) is an often refered to answer on explicit referencing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! I will edit the answer further. Did not want to introduce too many variables as the person who asked did not seem to use any at all :-)

Comment: Very true, do as you please.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response.  This will suffice.  Can you please suggest me best step by step video tutorials in YouTube to learn VBA as there are many and I am not sure which one to see and learn.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query I assume that you have 1000 rows and you have to hide next 4 rows if the value of the cell is <=0.

```
Sub Hide_Unhide()

Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To 1000
    If (Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("S" & i).Value)) And ActiveSheet.Range("S" & i).Value <= 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("S" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        i = i + 4
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out quickly.